# How can I run a specific class / utility in a Spring Boot application with wiring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle

I have my standard Spring Boot application working.  I have situations where I want to run a "job" which is basically some specific method normally run via a user doing something in their browser but I want to run it from command line.

I'm able to run an arbitrary class with gradlew;

```
./gradlew -PmainClass=kcentral.backingservices.URLMetaExtractor execute
```

However when run this way none of the "autowiring" works.  What is a better way to execute an arbitrary class (that has a main method) such that it also works with any Autowiring?

EDIT:

I got some advice to use a CommandLineRunner and some args, which work to execute the command via:

```
./gradlew bootRun -Pargs=--reloadTestData
```

However, the Autowiring of my Repo is failing.  What I have is:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableMongoAuditing
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses=KCItemRepo.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"kcentral"})
public class ReloadTestData implements CommandLineRunner {

  @Autowired
  AddItemService addItemService;

  @Autowired
  KCItemRepo itemRepo;

  @Autowired
  KCItemRatingRepo itemRatingRepo;


  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReloadTestData.class);


  public void reloadData(){
    log.info("reloadData and called");

    if (itemRepo == null){
      log.error("Repo not found");
      return;
    }
    long c = itemRepo.count();
    log.warn("REMOVING ALL items "+c);
    itemRepo.deleteAll();

    log.warn("REMOVING ALL ratings");
    itemRatingRepo.deleteAll();

  }
```

itemRepo is always null even though I wire the same way in my 'regular' spring boot app without an issue.  What do I need to do to have it wire properly?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you say you want to run a "job" suggests that you might want to use a scheduled task within your application, rather than trying to run it through the command line. e.g. [Scheduling tasks in Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/)

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
public void reportCurrentTime() {
    log.info("The time is now {}", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
}
```

If you want to make a command line application work with Autowiring, you can make a command line application by making your Application class implement the `CommandLineRunner` interface, e.g. [Spring Boot Console App](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-console-app)

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootConsoleApplication 
  implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootConsoleApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
    }
}
```

And add `spring.main.web-application-type=NONE` to the properties file.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, basically from 1 project I want ./gradlew bootRun to run my regular spring boot app (handling web requests) but ./gradlew bootRun -Pargs=something to run some extra stuff before starting up (or even better just run the extra stuff and then stop).  See the edit to the original post, that's what I'm trying to do, but the wiring isn't working.

Comment: If you want to run a task after the application is ready, listen to a Spring application event, as with http://javainfinite.com/spring-boot/springboot-applicationreadyevent-applicationfailedevent-contextrefreshedevent/ You might want to read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem to improve your question and get more useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop the application after running you can use `SpringApplication.exit(ctx)`. Don't know about your auto-wiring problem though, maybe try printing out the list of available beans which might give some insight. Example:

```java
@Component
public class DoThenQuit implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Override
    public void run(String[] args) {
        // do some other stuff before quitting
        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.stream(beanNames).forEach(System.out::println);
        
        // then quit the application
        SpringApplication.exit(ctx);
    }
}
```